# Cannot load JSON from php/mysql in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to build an IOS App for my php/mysql website. The problem is I can't get the following code working with my created JSON output. But the same code works with other APIs like :

http://www.telize.com/geoip

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Playground - noun: a place where people can play

        let urlPath = "https://www.example.com/API_OUT.php?API_KEY=785d...e5f5"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            println("Task completed")
            if((error) != nil) {
                // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if(err != nil) {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {

                println(jsonResult)

            }

        })
        task.resume()       
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks ok. You suggest that it doesn't work, but don't tell us precisely what it does. Does the network request fail? Does the JSON parsing fail? Where precisely is this failing? What error, if any, does it report?

Comment: Hi,There is no error in xcode console but the App crash with EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT subcode=0x0)

Comment: Please provide sufficient information: 1) was "Task completed" printed? 2) did you step through the code to see on which line it crashed? (Also, it should be `println(jsonResult.description)`.

Comment: Yes Task Completed printed. It doesn't show which line is causing the issue, but when I replace the URL with http://www.telize.com/geoip it works fine !!!!

Comment: WHERE does your app crash????

Comment: Here is your bug: `as NSDictionary`.  Learn how to read JSON.  If you go to json.org you can learn the syntax in 5-10 minutes.

Comment: And learn how to get the exception message and exception stack trace.  You need those to not get downvoted on an iOS crash question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSON is an array, not a dictionary (unlike your original JSON, which was a dictionary). Thus your assignment of this new JSON to a dictionary will fail.

I would suggest (a) use `NSArray` rather than `NSDictionary`; and (b) use `if let ...` syntax rather than just `let`, to gracefully handle these errors in the future.

Thus, that yields:

```
var parseError: NSError?
if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? NSArray {
    println(jsonResult)
} else {
    // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
    println("JSON Error \(parseError?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: BTW, I don't advise `.MutableContainers` unless you really need mutable containers. Hence my use of `nil`, above.

Comment: Actually, there's no problem with using mutable containers unless you're obsessed with "encapsulation".  Mutable is probably very slightly faster than immutable.

Comment: Agreed. But, I never use mutable unless I absolutely have to, less for performance reasons than general code maintainability (less chances of introducing unintended consequences later, easier to analyze/debug code later, etc.). The purpose of my comment, though, was not to make a big deal about it, but rather to let OP know that this unrelated edit was a conscious decision, not some an oversight on my part.

Comment: Thanks I used you code and it's working fine now. Is there a way I can make my JSON as dictionary ?

Comment: Assuming you control the server code, you can make your JSON whatever you want. Right now it's an array of dictionaries. Usually the structure is dictated by the nature of the data being returned. If always returning only one item, then a dictionary makes sense. If returning potentially more than one item, then an array of dictionaries makes sense. If you want to change your server code, but are unclear how to do that, then that's certainly a separate question here on S.O.